# What is the relationship between Coriolis forces and Angular momentum?

Tags: angular-momentum, coriolis-effect

Recently I did an assignment about helicopters, and during the oral exam we talked about Coriolis forces. I know where it comes from, and I've seen the derivation: [Example](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/os/wind/deriv.shtml)

In the case of helicopters, it increases the blade speed as a consequence of flapping, like explained in [Coriolis helicopter](http://www.pilotoutlook.com/helicopter_flying/coriolis_effect_(law_of_conservation_of_angular_momentum))

[image: Helicopter Coriolis]

I understand that through flapping, the center of gravity moves inward, and conservation of angular moment dictates that the speed should increase.

I mentioned to my lecturer that we do not really need Coriolis forces to explain this effect, as it can be explained by conservation of angular momentum only. Only when you state that the Coriolis force are the forces that ensure conservation of momentum, it makes sense. However, she said that the Coriolis forces are actual forces as a consequence of a rotating reference system, and not a consequence of angular momentum.

**To me, it seems that the Coriolis force is a force that ensures conservation of momentum.
E.g. we know that the speed increases when the distance to the C.o.G. decreases, but the Coriolis forces are the actual forces that enforce the acceleration.**

Is this the right way to look at it?

Comment: Coriolis is really a kinematics term, whereas forces and momentum are not involved. It is a result of a changing vector on moving reference frame.

Comment: maybe you would like to look at [this historical article about coriolis force](http://www.meteohistory.org/2005historyofmeteorology2/01persson.pdf), coriolis force as an inertial force is assigned to the relative motions betwen systems of objects

Comment: Yes, you are right. What can one say more :) Just like for the centripetal force: In a moving reference frame you experience a force (you need it, to explain weird behaviour), from outside this frame it looks like inertia.

Comment: You also have to add to the tangential velocity, the velocity of going up and down which increases the incident speed _and_ alters the angle of attack.